# problem in installing fresh magento with same old database

Tags: database

I installed fresh magento with same old database.Now the images are not showing up in my new store and the when I open my old store, It is redirecting to the new store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is Magento 1.x ...

In your database: `SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE '%base_url'`. The values there should point to your intended url. That should also fix your images; I'm guessing the URL points to your old store. You probably will need to clear your cache and reindex after.

Comment: Hey thanx.The mistake was I didnt Copy my old media file. Anyway your comment also guided me. thanx